# Hyphen/ Dash Breaking The Search

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

When The Name contains a hyphen it can't fetch the correct row.
It actually isn't fetching anything

XAml:

```
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=Entities"
        DefaultContainerName="Entities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="CustomerClassifications">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>

        <div class="searchWrapper">
            Search
            <asp:Panel DefaultButton="btnSearch" runat="server" ID="pnlSearch">
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxSearch" runat="server" CssClass="tbxSearch">
            </asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" CssClass="btnSearch" Text="Search" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
```

Code Behind:

```
            this.EntityDataSource1.WhereParameters.Clear();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbxSearch.Text))
            {
                this.EntityDataSource1.Where = "1 = 1";
            }
            else
            {
                this.EntityDataSource1.Where = "it.Name =  @Name ";
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are clearing `WhereParameters`, but using parameter `@Name` in the second where clause. I think you should not clear the `WhereParameters`.

Comment: ok i removed the clear... but am still having the same problem.  The search is working only when there is a hyphen "-" it wont fetch the row

Comment: Then try to capture the SQL being executed using SQL Server Profiler. It's easy. Please post the SQL in its entirety.